# Как преобразовать object в array в React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Добрый день всем! Начал изучать реакт и столкнулся с проблемой. Данные, которые я получаю от API и закинул в пропс хранятся в виде object. Как только начинаю перебирать map или forEach ничего не выходит. Начал искать способы конвертнуть из объект в массив, но преобразование проходит не очень успешно. Если в объекте есть вложенные объекты, то вложенности не становятся array. Подскажите как можно преобразовывать данные в массив или вовсе обходится без этого, чтобы это не выглядело плохо? 
Вот пример моих данных:

```
{
    id: '1',
    name: "BMW",
    model: "3-series",
    count: '110',
    image: "http://media-dmg.assets-cdk.com/teams/repository/export/v/2/4bd/264d8b39610058e0a0050568ba825/4bd264d8b39610058e0a0050568ba825.png",
    colorHex:'212121',
    color:'aqua Dark',
    equip:'Basic',
    info: {
        engine:'benzin',
        year:'2018',
        ph:'160',
        transmission:'auto',
        drive:'front'

    },
    prices: {
        lease:'220',
        cash:'30000',
        credit:'300'
    },
    specifications: {
        basic: {
            interior: {
                0:'Обивка сидений, ткань Firework',
                1:'Передний подлокотник',

            },
            climate: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',

            },
            exterior: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',

            },
            comfort: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
            },
            multimedia: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',

            },
            security: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
            }
        },
        add: {
            interior: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',
            },
            climate: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',
            },
            exterior: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',
            },
            comfort: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',
            },
            multimedia: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',
            },
            security: {
                0:'Крыша и корпуса внешних зеркал в цвет кузова',
                1:'Обогрев форсунок омывателей и внешних зеркал',
                2:'Электрический корректор фар',
                3:'Противотуманные фары',
                4:'15-дюймовые легкосплавные диски Heli Spoke, серебристого цвета',
            }
        },
        character: {
            fuel: {
                city:'9',
                all:'7',
                track:'8'
            },
            speed: '8'

        }
    }
},
```

Хочу доставать информацию, например о ценах

```
          renderPrices(title, price) {
        const {classes} = this.props;
            return (
                <div>
                    <Typography className={classes.titlePrice}>{title}:</Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.price} component="p">
                        {price}<br />
                    </Typography>
                </div>
            )
        }

    render() {

        return (
            <CardContent>
{this.props.viewModel.prices.map ((key, price)=> this.renderPrices(key, price))}
            </CardContent>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам нужно преобразовывать объект в массив? Не понял из вопроса.